# How to do jndi lookup of MQ connection factory defined in Websphere app Server from Spring

Tags: spring, jndi, ibm-mq, lookup

I am trying to connect to a MQ connection factory defined in Websphere app Server 7.0.

But I couldnt find a right connectionfactory interface for the MQ to define in Spring.

However when I tried to hardcode the connection details in the spring config file, I am able to connect to the Queue Manager.

What is the right interface/format to use in Spring beans to load the MQ connection factory defined in Websphere appl server?

**Working Code**

```
<bean id="mqConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
    <property name="hostName">
        <value>127.0.0.1</value>
    </property>
    <property name="port">
        <value>1414</value>
    </property>
    <property name="queueManager">
        <value>MYQM</value>
    </property>
    <property name="transportType">
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Not Working Code**

```
<bean id="mqConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="jms/WASQM"/>
    <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false"/>
    <property name="cache" value="true" />
    <property name="proxyInterface"  value="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactoryFactory" />
</bean>
```

where WASQM is the MQ connection factory defined in Websphere

**Error with the Non working code**

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mqConnectionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/config-mq.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactoryFactory] is not an interface
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactoryFactory] is not an interface
```

I need help in replacing the not working code with a right code.
Spring - 3.0.5
IBM MQ and Web App Servers - 7.0

Answer (score 4):

Right way to do is

1. Create the resource in Queue Connection Factory in Websphere App Server (not in Connection Factory)
2. Use javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory as the connection factory in spring config

   ```
   <bean id="mqConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
      <property name="jndiName" value="WASQM"/>
      <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false"/>
      <property name="cache" value="true" />
      <property name="proxyInterface"  value="javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory" />
   </bean>
   ```

This [page](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14126948) gave me the hint.