# SpringBoot application and connect to Websphere MQ Activation Specification using Camel

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, jndi, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I have a Springboot application and I need to connect to Websphere MQ Activation specification JNDI using Apache Camel.

Can anyone suggest how can I do it and what is the best approach?

Comment: try this http://lowry-techie.blogspot.com/2010/11/camel-integration-with-websphere-mq.html

Comment: Any specific example related to activation specification and JNDI?

Comment: @ArunAbraham RamPrakash showed linked how to plug a WebsphereMQ into a jms component.  Creating a JNDI lookup is a fairy standard Java EE practice when dealing with external resources since the container can manage them.  Here is a post showing your WMQ config: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15546685/how-to-do-jndi-lookup-of-mq-connection-factory-defined-in-websphere-app-server-f

Comment: Thanks. I had a look at it and was able to get it working with ConnectionFactory. But Activation specification is what I am struggling with.